# Simpler solution to this nginx config?

Tags: nginx, web-server

When I setup a website with ssl, I almost always have this boilerplate nginx config (instructions in comments):

```
# Redirect both (http/https) non www. to www.
server {
  listen 80;
  listen               443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/www.example.com.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/private/www.example.com.key;

  server_name example.com;

  return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

# Redirect www. http traffic to www. https
server {
  listen      80;
  server_name www.example.com;
  return 301  https://$host$request_uri;
}

# Serve www. website over https
server {
  listen               443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/www.example.com.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/private/www.example.com.key;

  server_name     www.example.com;
  root            /home/example/apps/site;

  server_tokens off;

  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  # ...
}
```

Anybody has suggestion make this simpler and remove some duplication?

Comment: That _is_ the simpler solution!

Comment: Still i do not see the point of your second server block. Why can't you remove it, add `www.example.com` to the first block and substitute `$scheme://` with `https://` ? As far as i see you'lee have the same functionality.

Comment: @Glueon I get `nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored` when I put `server_name example.com www.example.com;` in the first server block with `https://` instead of `$scheme://`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a wildcard certificate for `*.example.com`, this is possible to write it under this form :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/www.example.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/www.example.com.key;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.example.com;

    root /home/example/apps/site;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    [ ... ]

}
```

The SSL handshake will always occur in the first block thus providing the wildcard domain certificate.

The `server_name` election, as it's SSL, is done after the handshake and allows this form of configuration where the right server block is not necessarily the one in which the handshake occured.

The `default_server` directive will force redirection of unknown/empty/non-existent Host headers to the HTTPS domain.

Comment: What is the first server block for? It seems to be redundant. The third one can be used as a default SSL virtual host.

Comment: @Glueon No it can't because you want to redirect between two domains. The first server block is a "catch all traffic" for SSL handshake.

Comment: And if i use the "default" keyword?

Comment: @Glueon then you need to test with a if block the `$host` for each request going through this server block.

Comment: Ah I understand what you are trying to say. But it seems that @allaire either has a `default` virtual host or it's not needed. In second case it's ok to show `www.example.com` for any connection which unmatched `server_name` condition therefore we can get rid of that first section.

Comment: @Glueon I don't really get what you are saying. You still need redirects to avoid duplicate content in SEO.

Comment: @Glueon Oh I think I got what you say, yes we can factorize this more by removing the second block and merging it into the first one. Updated answer.

Comment: Yeah. Now it looks ok :)